# how to pass a variable through .js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from page 1, that has a javascript that uses a .js file for the submit button.  I want to take that variable and pass through the .js file to a frames page that needs to output that variable again.

Here is the "button" I am trying to pass the variable (located in the .js file)

```
 window.location = SC.baseUrl + '/reservation/' + reservation.token;
```

The variable I am trying to pass is called $event_name

The variable is being queries from mySql and I am using codeigniter.  When the page loads, the query filles in the event name, which I am then trying to pass that variable into another page through this .js script.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't pass variables between 2 separate JS files.

Comment: have you tried using cookies or localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass variables between 2 separate JS files. What you could do is have functions in both files that return something. For example:

**JS File 1**

```
function myFunction1 (arg1) {
     return arg1;
}
```

**JS File 2**

```
function myFunction2 () {
     return myFunction1 ("foo"); //myFunction1 is in a separate JS file
}

alert(myFunction2()); //Throws alert message that says "foo"
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>

            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Both files would have to be loaded into the same page, of course. **KIND OF** the same concept of using jQuery or some other JS Library with your code.

Comment: What about including the second function in the first and passing the variable? function(variable1){somecode; var returnVar=function2(variabletopass); return returnVar;} function2(variable2){somecode; return variabletoreturn;}. On my phone, so realize not exact code.

Comment: You just need to make sure that if your referencing a variable in JS File 1, JS File1 is loaded in the DOM before you reference anything in it. So this means that you'd need to load JS File 1, then JS File 2 if you want JS File 2 to reference something in JS File 1

Comment: i am trying to pass the variable from one php page to another, but the button used to load the 2nd page is through the .js file.  I hope I am explaining it right.

Comment: Please upload your code so I can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into using [browser cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).